# How do I prove a subspace is discrete?

Tags: general-topology

The original problem asks the following:
\begin{equation}
\text{Prove that } \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \text{has a subspace } X \text{ that is } T_4 \text{ but not Lindelöf}.
\end{equation}

Additionally, I was given the following hint:
\begin{equation}
\text{ Start by proving } \{f_r \text{ | } r \in \mathbb{R}\} \text{ where } f_r(x) = 1 \text{ if } x=r \text{ else } 0 \text{ is discrete.}
\end{equation}

Thus far, I know my proof has to take the following steps:

(1) Prove $\{f_r \text{ | } r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is discrete.

(2) Since said subspace $X$ is discrete, it satisfies all the separation axioms.

(3) Since it is uncountable discrete, it is not Lindelöf.

The main snag I hit is in step 1. If any other steps in what I perceive to be the proof process are wrong, feel free to correct me/elaborate!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To show your subspace $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is discrete, you should be looking to find open sets $U_r$ whose intersections with $X$ give you the singletons $U_r \cap X = \{f_r\}$. Given what open sets in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ look like, what seems reasonable to try?

Comment: Find a member $B_x$ of the (canonical) base (basis) such that the only $f_r$ in $B_x$ is $f_x.$....  So $\{f_x\}=B_x\cap \{f_r:r\in \Bbb R\}$ is an open set of the sub-space  $\{f_r:r\in \Bbb R\}.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $\pi_r:\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}\to\Bbb R$ be the '$r$th projection', i.e. the evaluation at $r$, and consider the open set $\pi_r^{-1}(\frac12,\frac32)$.